# Visual Studio Model Won't Show SOME New Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-express, edmx

I added some tables to my DB, and refreshing the model didn't work.  So I deleted my .edmx file completely.  I then recreated the model according to my updated DB, but the same tables were still missing.  I'm not really sure why, but for some reason it won't load certain tables into the model.  I looked at the XML .edmx and the tables are listed at some points of the file...so I'm not really sure why they won't appear.  Any tricks anyone knows that I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the tables in question implement a many to many relationship between two other entities, and have only two columns, both of which are foreign keys to the other tables, they will be subsumed into the relationship instead of surfaced as separate entities in the model.

If that's not it, check your connect string, and make sure it's pointed where you think it is.

If that still doesn't solve the problem, edit your question and add the DB metadata for the "missing" tables.

Comment: I just went over the tables and it seems that your first answer explains what is happening.  How do I surface them as separate entities?

Comment: So, I think I figured a way around it...I just added dummy columns to the tables, rebuilt the model and deleted them once my missing tables showed up in the model.  Thanks!